# Nginx Static Build - Run as root with a non-root user

Tags: root, nginx

I have compiled nGinx statically and it is working fine. How i can create a NORMAL user and run the nginx static bin as root when i start it from the normal user?!

Thank you

Comment: That sounds like the absolute opposite of what most people want their webserver to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is how to give a non-sudo user permissions to allow Nginx to bind to privileged ports.

If that is the case then in the `/etc/sudoers` file (shortcut `visudo`) add these lines:

```
Cmnd_Alias   NGINX = /path/to/binary/nginx
username ALL=NOPASSWD: NGINX
```

Of course in the above example you need to change the `/path/to/binary/` to match where it is on your system, and the `username` to be the username you wish to run the command.

You can also achieve the same result by instead of using a username only, creating a NGINX group and all users in that group have that permission.

```
groupadd groupnamehere
usermod -G groupnamehere usertoaddtogrouphere
```

Now inside the `sudoers` file, replace the `username` line I gave above with this one:

```
%groupnamehere ALL=NOPASSWD: NGINX
```

To test this, become the user, and execute the command:

```
1)Become the user =>  su - usernamehere
2)Check groups user is in => groups
3)Run command => sudo nginx restart
4)In case nginx isn't a global command run => sudo /path/to/binary/nginx restart
```